# Seeking knowledge on array of arrays memory performance

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

Context: Multichannel real time digital audio processing.

Access pattern: "Column-major", like so:

```
for (int sample = 0; sample < size; ++sample)
{
    for (int channel = 0; channel < size; ++channel)
    {
        auto data = arr[channel][sample];
        // do some computations
    }
}
```

I'm seeking advice on how to make the life easier for the CPU and memory, in general. I realize interleaving the data would be better, but it's not possible.

My theory is, that as long as you sequentially access memory for a while, the CPU will prefetch it - will this hold for N (channel) buffers? What about size of the buffers, any "breaking points"?

Will it be *very* beneficial to have the channels in contiguous memory (increasing locality), or does that only hold for very small buffers (like, size of cache lines)? We could be talking buffersizes > 100 kb apart.

I guess there would also be a point where the time of the computational part makes memory optimizations negligible - ?

Is this a case, where manual prefetching makes sense?

I could test/profile my own system, but I only have that - 1 system. So any design choices I make may only positively affect that particular system. Any knowledge on these matters are appreciated, links, literature etc., platform specific knowledge.

Let me know if the question is too vague, I primarily thought it would be nice to have some wiki-ish experience / info on this area.

**edit:**

I created a program, that tests the three cases I mentioned (distant, adjecant and contiguous mentioned in supposedly increasing performance order), which tests these patterns on small and big data sets. Maybe people will run it and report anomalies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

const int b = 196000;
const int s = 64 / sizeof(float);
const int extra_it = 16;
float sbuf1[s];
float bbuf1[b];

int main()
{

    float sbuf2[s];
    float bbuf2[b];
    float * sbuf3 = new float[s];
    float * bbuf3 = new float[b];
    float * sbuf4 = new float[s * 3];
    float * bbuf4 = new float[b * 3];
    float use = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        using namespace std;

        int c;
        bool sorb;

        cout << "small or big test (0/1)? ";
        if (!(cin >> sorb))
            return -1;

        cout << endl << "test distant buffers (0), contiguous access (1) or adjecant access (2)? ";

        if (!(cin >> c))
            return -1;


        auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        if (c == 0)
        {
            // "worst case scenario", 3 distant buffers constantly touched
            if (sorb)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < b * extra_it; ++k)
                    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
                    {
                        sbuf1[i] = k; // static memory
                        sbuf2[i] = k; // stack memory
                        sbuf3[i] = k; // heap memory
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < s * extra_it; ++k)
                    for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
                    {
                        bbuf1[i] = k; // static memory
                        bbuf2[i] = k; // stack memory
                        bbuf3[i] = k; // heap memory
                    }
            }

        }
        else if (c == 1)
        {
            // "best case scenario", only contiguous memory touched, interleaved
            if (sorb)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < b * extra_it; ++k)
                    for (int i = 0; i < s * 3; i += 3)
                    {
                        sbuf4[i] = k;
                        sbuf4[i + 1] = k;
                        sbuf4[i + 2] = k;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < s * extra_it; ++k)
                    for (int i = 0; i < b * 3; i += 3)
                    {
                        bbuf4[i] = k;
                        bbuf4[i + 1] = k;
                        bbuf4[i + 2] = k;
                    }
            }

        }
        else if (c == 2)
        {
            // "compromise", adjecant memory buffers touched
            if (sorb)
            {
                auto b1 = sbuf4;
                auto b2 = sbuf4 + s;
                auto b3 = sbuf4 + s * 2;

                for (int k = 0; k < b * extra_it; ++k)
                    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
                    {
                        b1[i] = k;
                        b2[i] = k;
                        b3[i] = k;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                auto b1 = bbuf4;
                auto b2 = bbuf4 + b;
                auto b3 = bbuf4 + b * 2;

                for (int k = 0; k < s * extra_it; ++k)
                    for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
                    {
                        b1[i] = k;
                        b2[i] = k;
                        b3[i] = k;
                    }
            }

        }
        else
            break;


        cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - t).count() << " ms" << endl;

        // basically just touching the buffers, avoiding clever optimizations
        use += std::accumulate(sbuf1, sbuf1 + s, 0);
        use += std::accumulate(sbuf2, sbuf2 + s, 0);
        use += std::accumulate(sbuf3, sbuf3 + s, 0);
        use += std::accumulate(sbuf4, sbuf4 + s * 3, 0);

        use -= std::accumulate(bbuf1, bbuf1 + b, 0);
        use -= std::accumulate(bbuf2, bbuf2 + b, 0);
        use -= std::accumulate(bbuf3, bbuf3 + b, 0);
        use -= std::accumulate(bbuf4, bbuf4 + b * 3, 0);


    }

    std::cout << use;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

On my Intel i7-3740qm surprisingly, distant buffers consistently outperforms the more locality-friendly tests. It is close, however.

Comment: I suppose you couldn't write the code in a different language? [Fortran is fast with matrix ops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030201/performance-of-fortran-matrix-operations)

Comment: Technically, but the problem is kinda language-agnostic as it revolves around the hardware. It is usually only in C/C++ you run into these problems (HPC) where it is relevant to consider. C++ happens to be the choice language for most audio applications.

Comment: Is it possible to transpose the representation of the data to make the access type "row-major"? At least you would be sure of exploiting locality if it ever counts.

Comment: That would be equivalent to interleaving the data. Yes, that would be better as said but it requires transforming all the memory anyway, making the algorithm a double-pass. It also makes other stuff more complex (ie. operations needing only one channel has to traverse N more memory in those cases). The pattern in the OP is the exceptional, uncommon case, I would rather not gimp the common cases for this.

Comment: Real-time auio apps work with very *small* buffers. Access pattern won't likely matter. Your layout looks all right.

Comment: Yes, mostly. However you often work with audio history for the last couple of seconds, for instance, which is a pretty large amount of data. Hence, I've added a test that tests access patterns on small and large data sets.